# How to color code a column from an excel file in R?

Tags: r, data-science

I have to color code a column from an excel file i am importing. The problem is that the code is giving me an error "no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class "character"". I tried to convert the column to dbl and its still not working. Any help would be welcome thank you.

```
library(readxl)
library(condformat)
teast1 <- read_excel("Kenilworth_DataIssues-testR.xls",sheet = "Data Cleanup")
teast1 %>% mutate(ServiceWindows=as.double(ServiceWindows))
condformat(teast1[c(8:9)])%>%
rule_fill_gradient(ServiceWindows)
```

Comment: Don't you want to assign the result from line 4?

Comment: i can but im just mutating the column, also one problem is that its shooting back NA when converting the column.

Comment: I highly doubt that you are mutating `teast1$ServiceWindows`! In almost all cases`dplyr` does not mutate columns in place. If we want to change the object we have to re-assign the result of a dplyr operation.

Comment: ok thank you ill try it and see if it works

Comment: You can easily verify this by running `cars` then `cars %>% mutate(speed = speed * -1)` and then `cars` again...

Comment: AFAIK there are very few functions in R that mutate objects in place...

Comment: ok thanks for the help ill try to see if i can get it to work. the code works if i put a column name thats not a chr. for example on postal code it works because its not a chr.

Comment: Lol. But postal code *should* be a chr (we don't want to do math with it,  do we ;)?
If you want to recode `ServiceWindows` you could also call it with `as.numeric(ServiceWindows)` (or if it is stored as a factor we want to use `as.numeric(as.character(ServiceWindows))`), i.e. `condformat(teast1[c(8:9)])%>%
rule_fill_gradient(as.numeric(ServiceWindows))` if it is **not** a factor

Comment: i got it to work man thanks for the help